# Setting a Max Length for a Material-UI AutoComplete that uses free solo

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, maxlength

So I was using a Material-UI autocomplete with "free solo" set to true, and trying to limit the number of characters you can enter.

Just for reference, that's using 
"@material-ui/core": "^4.10.0",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.54",

I tried adding maxLength to InputProps on the inner TextField as an attribute with no joy.
I decided to post the answer, which I figured out, because it's NOT OBVIOUS.

Answer (score 13):

```
 <Autocomplete
                freeSolo
                options={
                  optionType === "alpha"
                    ? alpha_options.map((option) => option.behavior)
                    : beta_options.map((option) => option.behavior)
                }
                onInputChange={(event, value) => {
                  setBehavior(value);
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    className={classes.input}
                    inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, maxLength: process.env.REACT_APP_ENTRY_MAX_LENGTH}}
                    autoFocus={false}
                    margin="dense"
                    id="behavior"
                    label="Behavior"
                    placeholder="Complete this sentence"
                    type="text"
                    variant="outlined"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                )}
              />
```

Here are the CRUCIAL TRUTHS:

1) InputProps and inputProps are NOT the same thing.  From the MUI docs on TextField....

- inputProps: Attributes applied to the input element.
- InputProps: Props applied to the Input element. It will be a
  FilledInput, OutlinedInput or Input component depending on the
  variant prop value.

Yes, I know this is incredibly stupid and frustrating.

2) In an AutoComplete, the TextField is a child component of the AutoComplete itself.  In order to preserve that sweet, sweet AutoComplete functionality goodness, you have to pass the **AutoComplete**'s inputProps down to the TextField.

Hence this line:

```
inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, maxLength: process.env.REACT_APP_ENTRY_MAX_LENGTH}}
```

That is, using the spread operator, grab all the inputProps in the params, and spread 'em into the TextField's inputProps, then add to it with maxLength.  That process.env value is just one stored in my create-react-app's .env file.

You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you, it works! 
And when I tried to do this without spread operator, and it didn't work as expected. So, thank you for explanation too)

Comment: Any thoughts on how to limit the number of tags (as opposed to raw characters)? Been trying to puzzle out how to implement a "Pick three tags from list" solution.

Comment: @Kwhitejr Use `limitTags`. Reference: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values

Comment: An important note is that you need to use "inputProps" and not "InputProps", check that the lowecase one is the one that works

Comment: InputProps={{
    ...params.InputProps,
    inputProps: {
        ...params.inputProps,
        maxLength: 10 
    }
}}

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/23194